# For loop and echo in unix

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a shell script to list all the users who have id 101

```
       #!/bin/bash
       who="$(who | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort -u )";                                 
       #Save the output of who
       for user in ${who}; do                          # Iterate over $@
          if [ $(echo id -g $user) ==  "101" ] ; then
             echo "Got it";
          fi
       done;
```

when i execute my script I get this error "line 4: [: too many arguments".
I am not sure where I made mistake.

Comment: Did you try `$(id -g $user)`? Not sure why you need the `echo` there. The result of the command should be sufficient, I think.

Comment: another thing is don't use commands as Variable's name `who=... `

Comment: For that specific script, you're missing the `;` to close the `for` loop after the `fi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe changing the line to be:

```
if [ $(id -g $user) == "101" ]; then
```

will solve the issue. The original command had an `echo` in the output, which I believe is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not look directly at `/etc/group`?

```
awk -F: '$3==101 { print $4 }'
```

If `getent` is available on your host, you can do this to get a list pulled from `/etc/passwd` which is then chewed on:

```
awf -F: '{print $1}' <(getent group 101)
```

Comment: Or `gentent group...`

Comment: `getent` may not always be available on all POSIXes (e. g. MacOS), while `/etc/group` is easily parseable and should nearly always exist.

Comment: count AIX in there with not having `getent`, either. Just wanted to round out your answer.

Comment: Thanks but for some reason, it did not work. I got it work now

Comment: On macOS, /etc/group isn't the "real" groups list, just a stub that's used during boot and in single-user mode; the real list is in /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups/*.plist (and maybe in an LDAP server if it's bound to a domain, etc). So I really can't recommend using /etc/group if you're looking for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that `$( echo id -g $user )` will be expanded into the words `id -g username`.  This can not be compared to `101` since the expansion is unquoted.

To compare the output of `id -g "$user"` (note the double quotes), use

```
if [ "$( id -g "$user" )" = "101" ]
```

Within `[ ... ]` you should use a single `=` to do string comparison.  In shells that have `[[ ... ]]` you may use `==`:

```
if [[ $( id -g "$user" ) == "101" ]]
```

Here, the quoting of the command substitution is not required, but it is if you use `[ ... ]`.

---

The idiomatic way to do this sort of task is not to store the output of the `who` pipeline in a variable, but to pass it directly to the loop:

```
who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -u |
while read user; do
    if [ "$( id -g "$user" )" = "101" ]; then
        echo 'Got it'
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getent` to query the password database:

```
getent passwd 101
```